# Matrices multipilication 2x2 2x1 C#

Tags: c#, matrix

I have a 2x2 and a 2x1 matrix and want to multiply them. This is code.

```
 for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                for (k = 0; k < 2; k++)
                {
                    mulMatrix[k] = Mat1[i, j] * Mat2[j];
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think .NET already has a library for this. Read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.matrix.multiply(v=vs.110).aspx

Basically, the example is:

```
private void multiplicationExample()
{

    Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30);
    Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12);

    // matrixResult is equal to (70,100,150,220,240,352) 
    Matrix matrixResult = Matrix.Multiply(matrix1, matrix2);

    // matrixResult2 is also
    // equal to (70,100,150,220,240,352) 
    Matrix matrixResult2 = matrix1 * matrix2;


}
```

Comment: 3x3 matrix multiplication is not the same thing as what was asked

Comment: this library is not supportable on VS 2012

Answer (score 0):

Try [math.net](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/master/src/Examples/LinearAlgebra/MatrixArithmeticOperations.cs). Here's an example:

```
var matrixA = DenseMatrix.OfArray(new[,] { { 1.0, 2.0 }, { 4.0, 5.0 } });
var matrixB = DenseMatrix.OfArray(new[,] { { 1.0 }, { 2.0 } });

var result = matrixA * matrixB;
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

[See this .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JCkZZ2)